# Facebook Login using Cordova / React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, facebook, cordova, facebook-login

I have recently implemented Facebook Login using a plugin called **react-facebook-login**.

It works perfectly in a browser running on localhost. However when I build to device using cordova, I get the following error:

```
Application Error
net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND
(file://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id=***...
```

I assume the issue is the file:// before the facebook url which comes from Cordova I believe.

The Component looks like this:

```
<FacebookLogin
  appId="my-app-id"
  autoLoad={false}
  fields="first_name,last_name,email,picture,birthday,location{location{country, country_code, city, region}},gender"
  scope="public_profile, email, user_birthday, user_location"
  callback={LoginWithFacebook}
/>
```

Do I need to set a redirect uri? seems to be set to file:///android/.../index.html at the minute.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to modify the plugin to use `https:` [here](https://github.com/keppelen/react-facebook-login/blob/master/src/facebook.js#L192)

```
window.location.href = `https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth${getParamsFromObject(params)}`;
```

Comment: There is no src folder just dist?

Comment: then cmd+f for it in the dist folder and change it there https://github.com/keppelen/react-facebook-login/blob/master/dist/facebook.js#L124

Comment: Thanks I did, still broken?